# How does spring boot resolve PID thru ???? using log4j2

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

In spring boot's default `log4j2.xml`, `PID` is mentioned as `????`. I am not sure how log4j2 resolves this to actual PID

Does anyone have any idea how Spring boot makes log4j2 map this special code `????` to actual `process id (PID)`?

You can find the complete `log4j2-file.xml` at the below link

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2-file.xml#L4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot [sets a system property named `PID`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2f4751a6486f0b9c5653725cb3cb0b346524c03b/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/logging/LoggingSystemProperties.java#L106) when the application is starting up. The value of the `PID` system property is used by Log4j2 and replaces the `????` in the configuration file.

Comment: Can the `${sys:PID}` be replaced by `%pid` as this is currently resolved by log4j2 directly

Ref: https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/pattern/ProcessIdPatternConverter.java

Comment: It could, although the end result will be the same. Please open [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues) if you'd like your suggestion to be considered.